# Ubuntu 18 - Touchpad Buttons not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

I have installed Ubuntu 18 on my new Notebook

Everything works fine, except the right and left click Button of the touchpad. When I tap with one finger (left click) oder with two fingers (right click) on the touch field. It works, but not the mechanical buttons below...

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 PC Camera: PC Camera              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried to modify the synclient with

LTCornerButton
LBCornerButton
RTCornerButton
RBCornerButton

But I think this parameter are not the right ones...

Does anyone have an idea? Because every solution i find somewhere is for the problem, that the whole touchpad doesn't work...

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Does this answer work https://askubuntu.com/a/1067292/790920 ?

Comment: Hi, Martin what's the output of `xinput list-props 10`? you may want to look at *Capabilities* property or maybe other you may find relevant. You can use [this page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) as reference

Answer (score 2):

synclient has no effect because Synaptics is not the TouchPad driver on Ubuntu 18.04. Default installs use libinput instead.

Now, what kind of hardware do you have and what do we need to do to enable the buttons? Previous asked for info from X input. That may help.

Why isn't libinput just doing the right thing? More likely issue is your hardware is unfamiliar to libinput and the system is guessing incorrectly on measurements. Your buttons may be under the hand rest. Possible your attempt to config with Synaptics setting makes this worse.

What brand laptop, what model TouchPad?

Oh, does a USB mouse work?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I opened the bounty, because I have the exact same problem as the OP, even with the same ID (HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Touchpad) being displayed by xinput. The output of my xinput and of `xinput list-props 15` can be found here: https://pastebin.com/pLnWqKcD . My hardware: Its a Medion Akoya E3222 (see here; unfortunately the webpage is in German: https://www.medion.com/aldi/laptops/md62450-sued-de/). A USB mouse is working perfectly. I don't know how I can find out the TouchPad model, sorry.

Comment: Your pastebin file shows clearly that your system is trying to use Synaptics, not libinut.  So my guess does not help you, except if Synaptics is the wrong driver.  I think you have a decision here, whether to try to correct the parameters with what you have or change over to libinput.  libinput is the way of the future, Synaptics driver will eventually fade away. If you want to keep trying on Synaptics, first step is to run "synclient -l" to get a listing of the parameter it thinks it has now. Almost for sure, it does not know the correct boundaries of the touchpad device itself.

Comment: Note the OP said goal was to get buttons, but if his xprop output is like yours, I expect that means the settings are not available.  In yours, the one to concentrate on is Soft Button Areas, I think.  If you change over to libinput, the big difference will be that all of those detail settings disappear.  They are dedicated to creating correct for most user config files with the libinputs distribution.  Peter Hutterer is the contact point and he was very helpful with fixing many settings. (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput).  Unfortunately, links in that page are broken today.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same touch pad on a Geo netbook, and I can confirm that installing Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) solves this issue. From what I can tell it is a result of fixes in the 4.18 kernel, so any distribution with that kernel should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **gnome-tweaks** to solve this.
Launch Gnome Tweaks, and go to **Keyboard & Mouse** tab. Change the **Mouse Click Emulation** setting to **AREA**.
That should enable the buttons for you.

Answer (score 0):

On most Lenovo laptops the touchpad buttons are handled by the `TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint` device.

Check that you have the TrackPoint device and that the little red stick in the middle of the keyboard is working:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA801E:00 06CB:CECA Mouse               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA801E:00 06CB:CECA Touchpad            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

There were some issues with this device not waking up from sleep correctly (e.g. [1791427](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1791427)).